# Images are not triggering overflow-x scroll bar as expected in parent div

Tags: html, image

Hi I have been trying to create a simple image gallery, but am having issues getting the `overflow-x` scroll bar to appear when my images cumulative width reach a value greater than their parent `div`.

Check out this [fiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybrooks/7Xz8D/).

I just want to be able to resize the window and have the `overflow-x` scroll bar to appear when there are to many thumbnails to display horizontally within the available width of their parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest, and easiest way to achieve this is to add white-space: nowrap; to your container div and the images within it:

***CSS***

```
.container {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

img {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
    <img src="http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/artists/120_artist.png"/>
</div>
```

Should dynamically adjust as required, enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another pure CSS solution:

I placed the images in another div

```
<div style='height:100%; display: inline; white-space: nowrap;'>
```

check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xz8D/9/).

PS: I copied the images a few times just to show how it looks with more images. The inline css can be moved to a class or ID but that's up to you.

EDIT: Wrong link. Sorry, i replaced it :)

Answer (score 0):

**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xV3nA/)** should do the trick... There is a fixed width container for the thumbnail images which has a horizontal scrollbar when the contained images overflow to the right.

### HTML

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="thumbnails">
            <img src="http://www.drawingcoach.com/image-files/cartoon_trees_st5.jpg"/>
            <img src="http://www.aperfectworld.org/clipart/nature/cartoon_tree.png"/>
            <img src="http://84d1f3.medialib.glogster.com/media/23/23af5b409b4e973a9353048b062d73a33677c1f64c4b912a0aa6930081894f48/tree-cartoon-jpg.jpg"/>
            <img src="http://www.drawingcoach.com/image-files/cartoon_trees_st5.jpg"/>
            <img src="http://www.aperfectworld.org/clipart/nature/cartoon_tree.png"/>
            <img src="http://84d1f3.medialib.glogster.com/media/23/23af5b409b4e973a9353048b062d73a33677c1f64c4b912a0aa6930081894f48/tree-cartoon-jpg.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img class="fullpic" src="" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.gallery
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 120px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.thumbnails
{
    /* Arbitrarily large number */
    width: 10000px;
}

.gallery-container img /* larger size image */
{
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

.thumbnails img
{
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

### (Optional) JQuery

```
$('.thumbnails img').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.selected').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: can use like this $('.thumbnails img').click(function() {
    $(".fullpic").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});

Comment: @Pedro3M yes, you can. But I had meant to remove the .fullpic class (as it is not _required_)

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, and true it would produce the horizontal scroll bar, however, I really need the container for the thumbs to handle any number of images, so I cannot use a fixed width in this way for my requirement.

Comment: @Jez this will work for any number of images. Change the `.gallery` class to have a width of `100%` if you want and it will still work. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xV3nA/1/

Comment: @gvee I don't want to get into a discussion here, but this is a work around and depends on the width of the thumbnails div to fit in a certain amount of images. So thanks, but the cleanest answer is to just amend my original fiddle by adding 'white-space: nowrap' to the div that the thumbs are in, you shouldn't need an extra div inside that at all.